# No primary or single public constructor found for class java.io.File

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, axios

I'm trying to pass a file to my springboot backend. (which will then be uploaded to an s3 bucket), but I'm receiving this error that I can't figure out.

The file itself will contain an array, of an array of strings

Error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for class java.io.File - and no default constructor found either
```

Data Source -

```
// Data saved to S3 bucket / downloadableData function
if (this.lng !== "0.000000" && this.lng !== "") {
   this.locationData.push([`Longitude: ${this.lng}, Latitude: ${this.lat}, Uncertainty Radius: ${this.uncertainty_radius} meters, Address: ${this.place_name}, Source: TEXT`])
   this.locationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.locationData))
}
```

Axios Post -

```
downloadableData() {
  const blob = new Blob([this.locationData],  {type: 'application/json'});
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("document", blob);
  axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/targetLocation/uploadStreamToS3Bucket", blob)
},
```

Springboot method -

```
public void uploadStreamToS3Bucket(File locations) {
    try {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(String.valueOf(awsRegion))
                .build();

        String bucketName = "downloadable-cases";
        String fileName = connectionRequestRepository.findStream() +".json";
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, locations));
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1s3Q.png)

Comment: What do you mean by this statement -- "The file itself will contain an array, of an array of strings" That is a confusing statement.  What type of file are you trying to upload via a Spring BOOT app to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: @smac2020  I added a picture of the data at the bottom of my question. What I'm trying to do is create a file containing this data, and then upload that file to my s3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to upload a file that contain JSON data in it. This can be done in a Spring BOOT app via logic like this.

```
<p>Upload images to an S3 Bucket. Each image will be analyzed!</p>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

To handle this upload in a Spring Controller, you can use this logic:

```
    // Upload a file to place into an Amazon S3 bucket.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            String name =  file.getOriginalFilename() ;

            // Put the file into the bucket.
            s3Client.putObject(bytes, bucketName, name);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("photo"));
    }
```

Now you have the byte array and file name. You can place this into an Amazon S3 bucket by using the AWS SDK for Java V2.

```
     private S3Client getClient() {
    Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();

     return s3;
     } 

    // Places an image into a S3 bucket.
    public String putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {

      s3 = getClient();

      try {
        PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(bucketName)
                        .key(objectKey)
                        .build(),
                RequestBody.fromBytes(data));

        return response.eTag();

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Here is a complete document that shows this use case. This use case actually uses the Amazon Rekognition service to analyze photos in an Amazon S3 bucket; however, it still demonstrates how to successfully upload a file from your desktop to an Amazon S3 bucket Also - it's implemented using the AWS SDK For Java V2 - which is the version that Amazon Recommends.

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)